# What is the difference between JTextField.LEADING and JTextField.LEFT?

Tags: java, swing, jtextfield

I haven't found this anywhere before now.

`JTextField` can be found in `javax.swing` .
When I used both options, they appeared to have the same effect.

Are there any notable differences?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`LEADING` will be left or right, depending on your locale. Some folks write right-to-left.

Comment: then what is the JTextField.TRAILING meant for?

Comment: `TRAILING` will be right or left, depending on your locale. Some folks write right-to-left.

Comment: so it is just formatting preference, basically? There are no pros or cons of using any which style?

Comment: With `LEFT` you make it appear on the left side always, no matter what language is being displayed. With `LEADING`, it will go before the text (which could be on the right for some languages). Which one is appropriate depends on your application.